# Extremely slow speeds when tethering via usb

Tags: networking, windows-10, usb, performance, android

I finished building my new gaming PC today. Since my phone's (Galaxy S9) internet is usually much faster than my house's internet, I tethered it to my new computer. However, I'm experiencing much, much slower internet speeds than on my last PC. So, I ran a few speed tests. On my phone, I got around ~20Mbps download speeds. On my PC, I got around ~0.80Mbps download speeds. This seems to make no sense, as I even have USB 3.0 ports that I can plug into instead of the 2.0 ports I used to have. I tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1172282/windows-10-apps-slow-to-a-crawl-when-i-connect-to-the-internet-via-usb), but to no avail. I did recently buy a new USB-C cable for my phone, maybe that's the cause?

My phone's tethering speeds have never been this slow, and it's really starting to sour my new computer's freshness.

What could possibly be happening?

**Other info:**

Completely fresh install of Windows 10 Home.

Asus Prime X470-Pro motherboard.

Android Pie installed on my phone.

**EDIT:** I am already running RNDIS6. This is not my problem...

Comment: You're saying you're getting the slow speed on the computer connecting to the Internet through the phone's mobile data connection?  Have you tried as a comparison, downloading something stored on the phone?  If you suspect the cable, have you tried a different cable?

Comment: @fixer1234 I've tried different cables, wifi hotspot, and tethering to other computers. I'm starting to think that my carrier is throttling my speeds.